# Why I'm getting this Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component/

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern, react-dom

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

**This is my App.js code**

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      < Header />

    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Header.js code**

```
import React from 'react'
import './Header.css';
import PersonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Person';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';


function Header() {

    return (    
        <div className='header'>
            <IconButton>
                <PersonIcon fontSize="large" className="header__icon" />
            </IconButton>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Header
```

**I used my App.js in index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

When I remove `<PersonIcon>` and `<IconButton>` tags code works fine.

Comment: What are your React and Material versions?

Comment: material version: 4.11.3, react version: 17.0.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Try this

```
npm uninstall @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons
```

Then

```
npm i @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons
```

Restart the React server

```
npm start
// OR
yarn start
```

**Let me know if it works, Good Luck**

Comment: Maybe your network got interupted while installing `material-ui`

Comment: Crazy stuff, this fixed my app too. I re-installed twice (with npm and then yarn) but didn't work. But re-installing the `core` and `icons` did the trick. Thanks

Comment: I was having that same problem and but when I tried installing it I was getting an error during the install that told me to either do -force or --legacy-peer-deps the one that made it work for me was doing -force

Comment: Weird, but it works!! Commands for copypasters from 2022: `npm uninstall @mui/material @mui/icons-material` and `npm i @mui/material @mui/icons-material`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that in my case i installed the packages to the wrong folder, i wanted to share my solution just in case someone makes the same mistake as mine

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing the same problem of invalid hook call when I was installing Chakra UI.

Solution:

I was installing out of `src` folder of react.
Then I just gave a right click over `src` of react and clicked open-Integrated terminal and installed Chakra in src.
In that way, I solved my issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).